# R minimization - reuse objects computed in function in the calculation of gradient

Tags: r, optimization, optim

I want to do gradient-based minimization using a package like 'optim', where my function and gradient are quite complex. As you can see below in a simplified example, f calculates delta which is also necessary to compute for g. Within the same iteration, however, they are the same. Can I do optimization such that I don't need to compute it twice each iteration? It is the result of a fixed point problem with millions of parameters.

Any ideas? Or reference to a package?
Thanks

---

```
f <- function(par,dt,..){
  delta <- complexfunction(par,dt)
  obj_value <- complexfunction2(par,dt,delta)
  return(obj_value)
  }

g <- function(par,dt){
  delta <- complexfunction(par,dt) #it's the same as computed in the same iteration in f, can i cross reference?
  gradient <- complexfunction4(par, delta)
  return(gradient)
  }
```

I don't have a error code yet, I just don't know how to do it. Possibly creating a global and updating it each iteration?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I think we will need more detail than this, but typically you can construct your flow so that once-per iteration calcs aren't repeated.  Can you please try to either construct a reproducible example, or explain the full logic of what you need to do?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Hi, so I need to minimize the obj value coming out of f(). I want to do so using the gradient g() and an existing optimization package like 'optim'. Both need the input delta, that I reference above. If I use for example optim with nelder mead, I could supply f() and g() above to get a result. However, that would imply that within each iteration, delta is computed once inside f() and once inside g(). I am trying to minimize the run time and would like to compute delta only once every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the optimization algorithm, you could attach computations as an attribute to `par` and so pass it between gradient and objective function.  For an example of this, see Section "Updating" in
the [vignette of package `neighbours`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neighbours/vignettes/neighbours.pdf). (I am the maintainer of that package.) If you cannot do this, you could use an environment, as shown e.g. in https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2023-August/082759.html .

Comment: Dear Enrico, I do not have control over the optimization algorithm as I would be trying to use a package like 'optim'. Thanks for both references. I think I understand what you mean in the second reference.

Create environment EXAMPLE and supply to both functions. Update EXAMPLE$delta with delta in f(), then retrivere EXAMPLE$delta in g() and work with it. Could that work? Does optim do something similar with the parameters over which it is estimating? i.e. plug parameters from f() into g()?

Comment: In principle that should work, but in practice it's probably more complicated: there is no guarantee that a gradient-based method really calls the gradient in every iteration (it might for instance simply keep the search direction). So I'd start with putting messages into the objective function and the gradient to see when it is called, and perhaps also calls to `browser`. In sum, you'd need an additional check whether for a given `par`  your expensive computation's results are already available. If yes, use them; otherwise recompute. That might still save a lot of computation time.

Comment: Thank you. I may have misunderstood but I don't think that calling the gradient only every couple of iterations would make problems and I don't need a check.

Why? 
The objects are calculated in f(), so if the gradient is not called, I don't have an issue. The issue would occur if g() is calculated without the appropriate f() before. I.e. say the f() is calculated for par = 1, then g() is calculated (or not at all) for par = 1, that's fine. but if f(1) is calculated and then g(2), that would not work.

Do you think this could happen?

Comment: Again, in principle, it should work. But actual implementations might not exactly follow the principles, and so I'd add a check that the stored computation really "belongs" to the current value of `par` (and/or study `optim`'s code, and experiment).

Comment: ok yes, thanks, I now check the parameters supplied to g() with the last parameters calculated in f(), and recalculate delta if they are different.

Answer (score 1):

experiment/benchmark using memoise (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html)

If the time spent hashing the function inputs is faster than the complexfunction runtime then you might be onto a winner; its an empirical question.

Comment: What is the difference to storing the complexfunction result in an environment?

Comment: memoise is an existant , easy to adopt solution to memoisation problems; whereas the proposal to use an environment would require you to write code to achieve memoisation

Answer (score 0):

You suggested creating a global.  That's generally a bad idea, but you can create `f` and `g` in a way that lets them share access to some variables, or create `complexfunction` in a way that saves results and returns them if inputs are unchanged.  Here's an example of the latter:

```
complexfunction <- local({
  lastargs  <- NULL
  lastvalue <- NULL
  function(par, dt) {
    args <- list(par, dt)
    if (!identical(lastargs, args))
    {
       lastvalue <<- ... some complex calculation ...
       lastargs <<- args
    }
    lastvalue
   }
  })
```

This is a simple version of memoisation.  @NirGraham gave you a more sophisticated version; I think the `memoise` package retains multiple function values, not just one.